# Chaining of jQuery animate functions not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to chain some basic jQuery animations, but they are not working as expected. 
Only 1 `left`, `top` and `hide` animation is working.
I think this is something related to the `position` property of CSS but I'm not sure.

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/utkarsh17ife/L8rbene6/2/

```js
$('#move')
    .show(3000)
    .animate({left: "100px"}, 1000)
    .animate({top: "100px"}, 1000)
    .animate({bottom: "100px"}, 1000)
    .animate({right: "1000px"}, 1000)
    .hide(3000);
```

```css
#move {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
body {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="move">element here</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you've got to set the properties that you set previously to `null`, it seems to be saving the properties so you are getting conflicts without it:

```
$('#move')
    .show(3000)
    .animate({left: 100}, 1000)
    .animate({top: 100}, 1000)
    .animate({top:null, bottom: 100}, 1000)
    .animate({left:null, right: 1000}, 1000)
    .hide(3000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L8rbene6/3/